# Declaring Vec in Rust with 'static lifetime fails

Tags: rust, lifetime

I am learning Rust (having a C++ background), and struggle with declaring a vector with static lifetime.

Basically, I tried...

```
let v : 'static Vec<u16> = vec![1, 2, 3];
```

...but get `lifetime in trait object type must be followed by`+``

I think I don't get the syntax right, but can't find where the problem lies.

Comment: What do you want the `'static` to mean? `Vec<u16>` is always `'static`.

Comment: Ok, I see. But the same problem occurs with  `let mut v : 'static Vec<u16> = Vec::new();`

Comment: Right, the `mut` doesn't matter. You need to remove the `'static`.

Comment: Note that `'static` lifetimes in Rust have nothing to do with `static` declarations in C++

Comment: Ok, I see. I think what I intended was this: `static mut v : Vec<u16> = Vec::new();` So if I understand correctly, the 'static in my example was rather a requirement and not a syntax part that actually sets lifetime to static.

Comment: @user52366 that's hard to say since the `'static` in your example was invalid syntax, so it didn't mean anything. However an important point to remember about Rust lifetimes is that they are _declarative and not prescriptive_. IOW lifetimes specify how the code should behave and the compiler will check that the code does behave in a manner consistent with the specified lifetimes. But lifetimes can't _change_ how the code behaves.

Comment: You probably did not want this. `static mut` is almost always wrong. Perhaps you want `static V: Mutex<Vec<u16>> = Mutex::new(Vec::new())`?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [`lazy_static` crate](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/), and declare your vector as:

```
lazy_static {
    ref V: Vec<u16> = vec![1, 2, 3];
}
```

That works both inside a function and at top-level, and is the closest equivalent to C++'s `static std::vector<short> v = ...` inside a function. Unlike in C++, the vector will be immutable, so you might want to wrap it in a `Mutex` or `RwLock`.

Comment: Nowadays it's recommended to use [`once_cell`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/) (or standard [`OnceCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/cell/struct.OnceCell.html)/[`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html)), since it's usually less error-prone then macro-based solutions.

Comment: @Cerberus Thanks - I'm aware of both, but in this case went for `lazy_static` for its similarity to C++ `static`. The current situation is a bit frustrating because both `once_cell` and `lazy_static` are slated for deprecation in favor of the std solution, but `LazyLock` (the std variant of `OnceLock`) is sadly still not stabilized. This omission makes the two external crates still more ergonomic, especially for beginners.